# Monitor temperatures in a PC

Tags: windows, physical-environment

I'm experimenting with different locations and fans in my server. Whats a good program to monitor temperatures?

Comment: If it's really a server (not a regular PC with a Server SO) all the manufactures have specific software for the servers that are able to monitor them very nicely. HP, Dell, IBM... check the web and try them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpeedFan does a good job in most cases [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php)

Answer (score 0):

How about just using snmp?

Comment: The OP didn't specify which OS exactly, but on my W7 Pro machine SNMP does **not** provide any temperature data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Hmonitor](http://www.hmonitor.com/). This software is quite possibly the best hardware sensor monitoring of  softwares, temperature of any component on your PC/laptop/notebook/server with a sensor, including Core, CPU, mainboard, HDD, VGA/Graphics card temperatures and so on.